# How to add time to datetime field for all rows in mysql table when field is part of a unique key?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do this:

```
UPDATE `myTable` SET `time_stamp` = ADDTIME(`time_stamp`, '02:30:00');
```

However, 'time_stamp' is part of my unique key, and I get an error:
"Duplicate entry '2014-09-22 18:30:00' for key 'time_stamp'"

Is there a better way to do this? Do I have to go row by row starting from the latest time stamp? Or do something tricky like subtract time by some huge amount first and then add time?

Comment: The added time isn't always 2:30. That's just an example. This is actually part of a script, so that value is passed in as a parameter.

Comment: Yes a two-pass processing seems fine. First shift timestamps to avoid conflicts and then set real timestamps

Comment: change the conception of your table :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the question like you want to add 2h30m0s to every row in the table and that this is the reason, why you get your duplicate key error. In this case, just order descending, so that you don't update rows to a value that already exists.

```
UPDATE `myTable` 
SET `time_stamp` = ADDTIME(`time_stamp`, '02:30:00')
ORDER BY time_stamp DESC;
```

If you want to subtract however, you have to sort `ASC`ending.